# find a such function $f(x)$

Tags: functions

How to find a function $f(x)$ that satisfies:

1. $f(x)$ defines only on the positive axis of X;
2. when $x\to 0$, $f(x)\to +\infty$.
3. For a positive real number $k$, when $x\to k$, $f(x)\to 0$.
4. for $x\geq k$, $f(x)=0$.
5. $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\leq k$.
6. $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\leq k$.

I think it has a form of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ or something else, but I dont know how to drag the $\infty$ to $k$. Thanks.

Comment: Consider $1/x-1$ with $k=1.$

Comment: Well, you use a function that is defined a certain way for $]0;k[$, and a different way for $[k;\infty[$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is even smooth:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $x\ge k$}\\
\frac1xe^{-\frac{1}{k-x}}&\text{if $0<x<k$}\end{cases} $$

Comment: What a nice example! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $$f(x)=\begin {cases} \frac 1x-\frac 1k & x \le k \\0 & x \gt k \end {cases}$$